Auth Session Not Persisting After Login Attempt
I'm using Laravel 11 with MongoDB for authentication. However, after a successful login attempt using Auth::guard('web')->attempt(), the authentication session is not persisting, and Auth::user() returns null after redirection.
Environment:

Laravel Version: 11

MongoDB Package: mongodb/laravel-mongodb: ^4.7, mongodb/mongodb: ^1.19

PHP Version: [8.3]
user.php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use MongoDB\Laravel\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'users';
}

auth.php

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'store' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'store',
        ],
        'driver' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'driver',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admin',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],


    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'store' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'driver' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin\Admin::class,
        ],


    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1600,
            'throttle' => 1600,
        ],
        'store' => [
            'provider' => 'store',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1600,
            'throttle' => 1600,
        ],

        'driver' => [
            'provider' => 'driver',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 1600,
            'throttle' => 1600,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,




SESSION_DRIVER : file


Login Attempt Code:

Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => 'demo@gmail.com', 'password' => '123456']);
dd(Auth::user());


After a successful login, the authentication session should be persisted, and Auth::user() should return the authenticated user.
Actual Behavior:
Auth::user() returns null after redirection, indicating that the session is not being persisted.
What I've Tried:

Ensured that the session driver is correctly configured in config/session.php.

Verified that the users collection exists in MongoDB and contains the correct data.

Tried clearing the cache using php artisan cache:clear.


Question:
How can I ensure that the authentication session is properly persisted when using MongoDB with Laravel 11?

Could you clarify from which location you're redirecting to which location?

After attempting to log in with Auth::guard('web')->attempt(), I am redirecting the user to their profile page. There are no middleware in place affecting this flow.
From: The login endpoint or page (where the login attempt is made).
To: The user's profile page (where the user should be redirected after a successful login).

is profile page in same domain and subdomain as the login page is?
is profile page in same protocol (http and https) as the login page is?

i am using : http://localhost/client/demo/public/profile.i am print dd(Auth::user()) is null showing

When you log in using session-based authentication in Laravel, the session is managed using cookies to maintain login persistence. The cookies somehow must be received by browser. So you return them to browser with response. However, you don't need to manually return a response with cookies in your login route. Laravel automatically handles the session cookie for you.
make sure your login controller returns a standard response to browser not dd().

To resolve this, add the following lines to your bootstrap/app.php file to explicitly use the session bootstrap/app.php - bootstrap/app.php - add the line ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
$middleware->use([ \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,]); }
StartSession::class: This middleware is responsible for starting the session and managing session data, which is essential for persisting user login states.By adding these lines, you ensure that sessions are handled properly, and your authentication flow should work as expected, persisting the session after login.
